Using a multiplicative domain to assert when a Diophantine equation has non-trivial solutions
I've been reading Robert D. Carmichael's "Diophantine Analysis" that describes a way to get an $n$-parameter solution to a class of Diophantine equations by extending the solution set to one involving a multiplicative domain. Then it asks the reader to do an exercise and discuss when a non-trivial solution of some Diophantine equation exists, presumably using the described procedure. For example, it asks:
Determine the values of $m$ for which the equation $x^4 + m\,x^2\,y^2 + y^4 = z^2$ has non-trivial solutions.
How is the reader intended to go about this? I've managed to get a 2-parameter solution to this equation (4-parameter solution with 2 relationships connecting them) by extending the solution domain, but I'm not sure how to use it to show which such solutions exists.
Also, do the solutions obtained using this method represent all the possible solutions to the original equation? Would showing that the parameterized solution doesn't produce any non-trivial solutions for a specific value of $m$ imply there are no such solutions in general?

You should mention over which domain the equations are solved. For $x^4+mx^2y^2+y^4=z^2$ over $\Bbb Z$ we know by Fermat, that there is no non-trivial integer solution for $m=0$.

For this specific example, I suppose the intent is to solve it over the integers. I've copied the assignment from the book as is, and the domain is implied there, but given the context - I'd say that's right.

https://web.archive.org/web/20110305072539/http://maths.paisley.ac.uk/allanm/ECRNT/Ecrnt.htm

The prior link refers to Bremner & Jones, On the Equation $,x^4+mx^2y^2+y^4 = z^3,,$ J. Num. Th. 50, 286-298 (1995). $\ \ $

The answer to your question is too long for a forum post however it can be found in this paper by J.H.E. Cohn.

See also the links on the question for methods using elliptic curves. $\ \ $
